# How can i fix this error retrieving data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

This is the image of my data which is stored in the database.

[My Database img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED6vr.png)

'E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: com.example.pahalunitedfoundation, PID: 31028
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.pahalunitedfoundation.mainModel
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:29)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:15)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:36)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:108)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:148)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23059)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23059)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23059)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23059)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23059)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23059)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:804)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23059)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3622)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3082)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2075)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8512)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1076)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:826)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1061)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8056)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

below is the code written in my main main.java file below and i have deleted the imports in this question cos that was showing error

```
package com.example.pahalunitedfoundation;

public class Events extends AppCompatActivity {

  eventAdapter eventAdapter;
  RecyclerView recyclerView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<mainModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<mainModel>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("data"), mainModel.class)
                    .build();


    eventAdapter = new eventAdapter(options);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    eventAdapter.startListening();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    eventAdapter.startListening();
  }
}
```

below is the code of my adapter class (minus imports)

```
package com.example.pahalunitedfoundation;


public class eventAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <mainModel,eventAdapter.myViewHolder> {

  /**
   * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
   * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
   *
   * @param options
   */
  public eventAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<mainModel> options) {
      super(options);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull mainModel model) {
    holder.ename.setText(model.getEname());
    holder.date.setText(model.getDate());
    holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());
    Glide.with(holder.img.getContext())
      .load(model.getSurl())
      .placeholder(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
      .circleCrop()
      .error(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
      .into(holder.img);
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_item,parent,false);
    return new myViewHolder(view);
  }

  class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    // enter code here
    CircleImageView img;
    TextView ename,date,description;


    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img = (CircleImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        ename = itemView.findViewById(R.id.enametext);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also add the content of your `mainModel` class.

Comment: i have given a link of the image of my firebase database , please have a look !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error shows that you have string data in `data` node of firebase database. So this line of code unable to convert that string to `mainModel` type.

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<mainModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<mainModel>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("data"), mainModel.class)
                    .build();
```

So look out for the database on the firebase console and remove string if you have any inside `data` node.

**Best Practice,**

**Always give your class a capitalized name.**

For example,

Named like this,

```
public class MainModel
```

Instead of this,

```
public class mainModel
```

Answer (score 0):

A Few issues:
the listener probably should be stopped during onStop

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  eventAdapter.stopListening(); // was startListening
}
```

Also the stack trace directly seems to be related to the absence of any real adapter code for the `mainModel` class. If you could include this class it may help a bit. Right now the recyclerview is setup just try to instantiate a `mainModel` by passing it whatever is in `data` I assume it's a string.

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<mainModel> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<mainModel>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("data"), mainModel.class)
                .build();
```

If the constructor of `mainModel` doesn't take a `String`, an adapter would need to be made OR `mainModel` need to be updated to take a `String`

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing the following reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("data")
```

Along with "mainModel" class to FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder's "setQuety()" method, it means that you want to use the Firebase-UI library for displaying all "mainModel" objects that exist within:

```
root -> data
```

Which is actually not possible, since under that reference it exists only a child of type String, hence the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.pahalunitedfoundation.mainModel

To solve this, you need to add an extra level under your "data" node. This can be simply done using the DatabaseReference's [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) method. So when you are adding an object at the above reference, add it like this:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference dataRef = db.child("data");
dataRef.push().setValue(mainModelObject);
```

In this way, your database schema should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- data
       |
       --- $pushedId
             |
             --- date: "dd/mm/yyyy"
             |
             --- description: "this is a des"
             |
             --- name: "Pahal..."
             |
             --- surl: "https://..."
```

The code for getting the data may remain unchanged.